# Does anyone know of a good slider plugin in the post page for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins, slider

Does anyone know of a good slider plugin in the post page for wordpress that once you add media it would go into the slider

Answer (score 0):

Try these plugins. It will do the work,

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-flexslider/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-slider/
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I got the top post page slider plugin while searching, hope it  helps you .

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-post-slider/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-slider-ssp/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-plugin-random-post-slider/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/paged-post-slider/screenshots/